# How can I correct a site that can no longer be edited via the browser?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom-list

The problem: I have been trying a few things out in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and have managed to break one of the sites. A page now contains a custom web part that references  a list on a sub page, as I manually edited the ListID for this web part. I thought this could possibly work but alas not:

> List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.

Now I am unable to go back to this page to change the parameter back again. What is the simplist way to undo this mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to

```
{PageUrl}?contents=1
```

and then from that page delete the broken webpart

Comment: This was indeed the simplest way to correct this mistake.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the faulty one, this is the way to go. If you want to try to fix the issue, @teylyn's way is the right way

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Robert's answer: You can open the site with SharePoint Designer and edit the page. In code view the page will not be rendered and you can delete the web part.